# Using a multiline closure to execute commands in vimscript

Tags: vimscript, functions

I'm writing a script in which I am in need of closure functionalities. Take this function, for instance:

```
func! SetOpNorm(norm_comm, motion_key = 'y')
    let l:norm_comm = a:norm_comm
    let l:motion_key = a:motion_key
    let s:OpFun = { type, ... ->
        \ let l:NormFun = { sel ->
            \ sil exe 'normal!' l:norm_comm
            \ sil exe "normal! \<del>"
        \ }
        \ call function('s:MapOverOp', [l:NormFun, l:motion_key, a:type] + a:000)() }
    set opfunc=s:OpFun
endfunc
```

The script would work except for the fact that vimscript closures accept an `expr1` as their bodies and not a list of commands. Is there a way to work around this limitation?

I also tried using local functions to achieve the same result:

```
func! SetOpNorm(norm_comm, motion_key = 'y')
    let l:norm_comm = a:norm_comm
    let l:motion_key = a:motion_key
    func! OpFun(type, ...)
        func! NormFun(sel)
            sil exe 'normal!' l:norm_comm
            sil exe "normal! \<del>"
        endfunc
        call function('s:MapOverOp', [function('NormFun'), l:motion_key, a:type] + a:000)()
    endfunc
    set opfunc=OpFun
endfunc
```

But after some testing I think that this doesn't work as the inner local functions do not capture their sorrounding context.

Comment: Don't you need `closure` following the args of the inner function, per `:h func-closure` ??

Comment: If you mean `closure` as in a keyword I don't think so... I'm using neovim btw, mybe some things are different from regular vim

Comment: Nevermid... I just read `:h func-closure` and it looks like exactly what I need. Didn't bother to look before because I had already read `:h closure`. The naming might be a bit ambigous XD

Comment: I agree that it's not helpful having the information split across two sections although, to be fair, `:func-closure` is linked in `closure` (but the reverse isn't true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:h func-closure` to declare inner function as closure.

For an example of `g@` implementation using closures you can look into my plugin source code: [vim-opera](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-opera).

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem (and also my bigger problem of reinventing the plugin you're mentioning).